# Not displaying the IntelliSense in Visual Studio for Node.js

Tags: node.js, netbeans, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-code

I have installed a plugin for Node.Js in Visual Studio. If I use a standard library then IntelliSense works. For example: `var fs = require('fs');`.
It works well on some libraries such as 'azure': `var azure = require('azure');`. But if I use some other libraries using a package manager: `npm install telegram-node-bot`, Visual Studio does not show IntelliSense for it. Visual Studio Code and NetBeans have the same behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Speaking about NetBeans, the problem is that the (in particular) the `telegram-node-bot` uses ES6 (const, class...) and NetBeans don't support ES6 right now (it is being worked on for next NetBeans release). So the module is unparseable for NetBeans and it can't offer any code completion.